# "Not enough memory" error even though plenty of memory still available

Tags: memory

**Summary:**

The evaluation of an `Export[...]` expression fails with a "Not enough memory available" error, but the value returned by `MaxMemoryUsed[]` is well below the available memory reported by the `free -b` command.

---

I have a simple script (not a notebook) of the following form:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;  (* probably meaningless here *)

Get["dump_of_grid.mx"];  (* loads GRID *)

Export["grid.png", GRID];  (* error occurs when evaluating this expression *)

Print["MaxMemoryUsed: " <> ToString[MaxMemoryUsed[]] <> " bytes"];
Run["free -b"];
```

Basically, with the `Get` expression, the script loads from a `DumpSave`-generated file an item called `GRID`, and then it immediately attempts to export `GRID` to a *.png file.

More specifically, the script outputs the following:

```
Rasterize::bigraster: Not enough memory available to rasterize Notebook expression.
MaxMemoryUsed: 487726296 bytes
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:    33710690304 18287972352 15422717952  583143424  201375744 10360836096
-/+ buffers/cache: 7725760512 25984929792
Swap:   68499271680 4590067712 63909203968
```

So `MaxMemoryUsed` reports 487726296 bytes, while the external command `free -b` says that there are still 15422717952 bytes free.

In light of this, why would *Mathematica* fail with a "Not enough memory" error?

---

(It could be that *Mathematica* first computes how much memory the rasterization will require, and fails if the resulting number is greater than the available memory; if this is what happens, then the value returned by `MaxMemoryUsed[]` is not a fair estimate of how much memory *Mathematica* needs.  Is there some other way to get this estimate?)

Comment: it is just speculating, but it might well be that mathematica does what you expect: it tries to allocate memory for the rasterization, OS says nope, not enought memory and mma reports that it couldn't do what you wanted. As the name indicates `MaxMemoryUsed` implies that reports only how much memory actualy **was** used, not how much it tried to get. Of course it would be good to know how much it tried to get and didn't succeed, but unfortunately I think such functionality is not available.

Comment: What's in your `GRID`? Sometimes Mathematica tries to interpolate the data points and the resulted plots may be quite large. If that's the problem, then you may want to consider making a smaller plot by resampling, turn off interpolation, or using `Image[data...]` to construct the plots, etc.

Comment: Another thing you might keep in mind: Mathematica is generally not very economical with respect to memory consumption, which is especially true for the import and export functionality. It also seems worth mentioning that exporting graphics is to a large part done by the frontend and special code running in extra processes, so the memory consumption of those is not even reported by the kernel. Considering all that Mathematica might be the wrong tool for what you try to do. Can you give some background about what exactly you try to achieve?

Comment: I had a similar problem and temporarily created a 1 terabyte swap file. Despite this, Mathematica gave me the same error, long before it has used that much memory. I think there might  be some built-in limit re how much memory Mathematica can use.